# How do I replace appsettings.json values with .env variable in docker-compose command to launch an ASP.NET Core MVC app?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, environment-variables, appsettings

I have a C# / ASP.NET Core MVC app that I have been deploying via Docker. I have been hard-coding variables in the `appsetting.json` file and accessing them via calls like this for example

```
services.Configure<ApiEndpoints>(Configuration.GetSection("ApiEndpoints"));
```

in my `Startup.cs`.

But recently I started adding variables for deploying into a `.env` file and deploying like this `docker-compose --env-file .env up`. But I can't access the variables in my `.env` file in the .NET app.

For example I tried this

```
Console.WriteLine(Configuration.GetSection("APPSETTINGS_DB_STR"));
```

in `Startup.cs` where in the `.env` file I added this variable `APPSETTINGS_DB_STR=isThisLoggingCorrectly` and it logged as

```
amaranth_main               | Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
```

in my console... So how do I get the asp.net to access the docker .env variable?

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  data:

services:
  postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg:
    image: postgres
    # explicit container name
    container_name: postgresql_vlt_bg
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql_vlt_bg
  amaranth_main:
    container_name: amaranth_main
    links:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    depends_on:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
      - 8001:5001
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Release
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${Kestrel_Cert_Password}
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=${Kestrel_Cert_Rel_Path}
      - APPSETTINGS_DB_STR=${APPSETTINGS_DB_STR}
    volumes:
      - ${Kestrel_Cert_Abs_Path}:/https:ro
```

P.S. `POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD,` and `POSTGRES_DB` are being passed through just fine.

Comment: Try to use [docker-compose.override.yml](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration-files/docker-compose-override-yml.html), it should be useful to you. If it not helps you, pls share your docker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to first make `APPSETTINGS_DB_STR` into `APPSETTINGS__DB__STR`. Then I had to access the variable like this in my c# app code. `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(“APPSETTINGS__DB__STR”)`